# Address boundry error while using STL in C++

Tags: c++, list, runtime-error, breadth-first-search, state-space

I was writing the program for finding a path through an defined matrix.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

class maze{
    int inst[10][10];
    int m,n,initr,initc,finalr,finalc;
public:
    maze(int c){
        if(c==1) return;
        cout<<"\n Enter rows and colums: ";
        cin>>m>>n;
        cout<<endl<<"\n ENter initial configuration (1 for block, 0 for open):";
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                cin>>inst[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout<<endl<<"Enter initial state in row column:";
        cin>>initr>>initc;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter final state in row column:";
        cin>>finalr>>finalc;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(inst[i][j]==1) inst[i][j]=(-1);
            }
        }
        inst[initr][initc]=1;
    }
    bool up(int curr){
        int x,y;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                    x=i;
                    y=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(x==0) return false;
        if(inst[x-1][y]==0){
            //cout<<"\n up "<<x-1<<y; 
            inst[x-1][y]=curr+1;
            return true;
        }else return false;

    }
    bool down(int curr){
        int x,y;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                    x=i;
                    y=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(x==m-1) return false;
        if(inst[x+1][y]==0){
            //cout<<"\n down "<<x+1<<y;
            inst[x+1][y]=curr+1;
            return true;
        }else return false;

    }
    bool left(int curr){
        int x,y;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                    x=i;
                    y=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(y==0) return false;
        if(inst[x][y-1]==0){
            //cout<<"\n left "<<x<<y-1;
            inst[x][y-1]=curr+1;
            return true;
        }else return false;

    }
    bool right(int curr){
        int x,y;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                    x=i;
                    y=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(y==n-1) return false;
        if(inst[x][y+1]==0){
            //cout<<"\n right "<<x<<y+1;
            inst[x][y+1]=curr+1;
            return true;
        }else return false;

    }
    bool check(int curr){
        int x,y;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                    x=i;
                    y=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(x==finalr && y==finalc) return true;
        else return false;
    }   
    void print_maze(){
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            cout<<endl;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                cout<<"\t"<<inst[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

};

bool state_search(){
    int curr=1;
    maze start(0),temp(1);
    list<maze> queue;

    queue.push_back(start);
    while(!queue.empty()){
        start = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();
        if(start.check(curr)){
            start.print_maze();
            return true;
        }
        //start.print_maze();

        temp=start;
        if(temp.up(curr)) queue.push_back(temp);

        temp=start;
        if(temp.down(curr)) queue.push_back(temp);

        temp=start;
        if(temp.left(curr)) queue.push_back(temp);

        temp=start;
        if(temp.right(curr)) queue.push_back(temp);

        curr++;
    }
    cout<<"\n No answer found";
}


int main(){
    state_search();
}
```

This program works fine for most of the inputs. But gives an address boundry error for the following input

> Enter rows and colums: 4 4
>
> ENter initial configuration (1 for block, 0 for open):0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
>   0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
>
> Enter initial state in row column:1 0
>
> Enter final state in row column:3 3 fish: “./a.out” terminated by
>   signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Please suggest the possible reason for this error and how to correct it

Comment: at what line the error occur?

Comment: `gdb a.out`, `run` and find out where it is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized where the mistake was. I did not initialize `x` and `y` in the functions `maze::up()`, `maze::down()`, `maze::right()` and `maze::left()` as it was always supposed to be initialized by the function while traversing the matrix. The Error was in the algorithm itself. The variable `curr` from `state_search()` was supposed to denote the depth of the BFS tree. But since it was incrementing for every node found, it denoted the depth wrongly causing error whenever there were 2 possible paths.

To solve this issue, I removed the `curr` variable from `state_search()` and added it to the class definition initializing it to 1 and incrementing it whenever the functions `maze::up()`, `maze::down()`, `maze::right()` and `maze::left()` are called.

here is the complete working code

```
#include<iostream>
    #include<list>

    using namespace std;

    class maze{
        int inst[10][10];
        int m,n,initr,initc,finalr,finalc,curr;
    public:
        maze(int c){
            if(c==1) return;
            cout<<"\n Enter rows and colums: ";
            cin>>m>>n;
            cout<<endl<<"\n ENter initial configuration (1 for block, 0 for open):";
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    cin>>inst[i][j];
                }
            }
            cout<<endl<<"Enter initial state in row column:";
            cin>>initr>>initc;
            cout<<endl<<"Enter final state in row column:";
            cin>>finalr>>finalc;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    if(inst[i][j]==1) inst[i][j]=(-1);
                }
            }
            inst[initr][initc]=1;
            curr=1;
        }
        bool up(){
            int x=0,y=0;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                        x=i;
                        y=j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(x==0) return false;
            if(inst[x-1][y]==0){
                inst[x-1][y]=curr+1;
                curr++;
                return true;
            }else return false;

        }
        bool down(){
            int x=m-1,y=0;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                        x=i;
                        y=j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(x==m-1) return false;
            if(inst[x+1][y]==0){
                inst[x+1][y]=curr+1;
                curr++;
                return true;
            }else return false;

        }
        bool left(){
            int x,y=0;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                        x=i;
                        y=j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(y==0) return false;
            if(inst[x][y-1]==0){
                inst[x][y-1]=curr+1;
                curr++;
                return true;
            }else return false;

        }
        bool right(){
            int x,y=n-1;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                        x=i;
                        y=j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(y==n-1) return false;
            if(inst[x][y+1]==0){
                inst[x][y+1]=curr+1;
                curr++;
                return true;
            }else return false;

        }
        bool check(){
            int x,y;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                        x=i;
                        y=j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(x==finalr && y==finalc) return true;
            else return false;
        }   
        void print_maze(){
            cout<<endl<<endl;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                cout<<endl;
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    cout<<"\t"<<inst[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

    };

    bool state_search(){

        maze start(0),temp(1);
        list<maze> queue;

        queue.push_back(start);
        while(!queue.empty()){
            start = queue.front();
            queue.pop_front();
            if(start.check()){
                start.print_maze();
                return true;
            }

            temp=start;
            if(temp.up()) queue.push_back(temp);

            temp=start;
            if(temp.down()) queue.push_back(temp);

            temp=start;
            if(temp.left()) queue.push_back(temp);

            temp=start;
            if(temp.right()) queue.push_back(temp);
        }
        cout<<"\n No answer found";
        return false;
    }


    int main(){
        state_search();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't initialize **x** and **y** values in your up, down, left and right functions. And then if you don't find the indexes for curr, you access the **inst** array at random indexes.

In **right** function you should declare x and y like this:

```
int x = 0,y = 0;
```

In **left**:

```
int x = m - 1,y = 0;
```

Do the same in **right** and **left**.

Answer (score 0):

You use uninitialized variables `x` and `y` in method `maze::up`:

```
bool up(int curr){
    int x,y; // !!!
    ...
```

So when in following loops we didn't go inside `if` statement these variables still contain garbage from uninitialized allocated memory.

```
    ...
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(inst[i][j]==curr) {
                x=i;
                y=j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

And it's very high possibility that `x` is not in range [0, 10).

```
    ...
    if(x==0) return false;
    if(inst[x-1][y]==0){
    ...
```

And we immediately try to get value somewhere (`inst[x-1][y]`) far away in memory, and terminated with segmentation error.

---

**Fix**: It's better to initialize all the variables with meaningful values. Suppose that for your code this is correct solution:

```
bool up(int curr){
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    ...
```

You can tell to compiler to notify you when you keep somewhere uninitialized variables.

If you use GCC compiler you can use compilation flag:

```
g++ -O2 -Wuninitialized prog.cpp
```

And you will see a lot of similar places in your code.
Additionally you can use flag `-Wall`, and you will found that `bool state_search()` function reaches end without returning any value.